# Find Cell Address

Tags: excel

```
ColumnA Column B Column C
name    sales     index 
A       1250       1875 
B       5500     15000  
C        4500   5625    
F       12750   13125   
B       7250    28125   
F       2000    13875   
E       9250    23625   
F      39250    16875   
A       2250    25500   
B       7250    15750   
A       8250    29250   
B      16500    11625   
C        500    804000
```

In the above table I want to find out the cell address when F has maximum sales. Can somebody help me with excel formula.  e.g. in the above table the output will be B9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
="B" & MATCH(MAX(IF(A:A="F",B:B)),IF(A:A="F",B:B),0)
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  This will return the address of the first max value for "F" if there are equal values that are the max.

Also as noted by @XORLX Change the whole column references to the actual data size or big enough to cover what is needed.  This will speed up the calculation.  With the Array formula it will iterate through the whole column twice.  It will run over 2 million times.

Though the real question is for what purpose are you going to use the answer? If the end is to merely know the address then use the above.

But if not then there may be a way to get to the end in one step.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Scott.I am really grateful to you.Actully i have an excel sheets of various strikes in the option chain of stocks. I wanted to find the strikes which have maximum open interest and also the change in open interest is maximum in that strike.

Comment: @piknooselvan please mark as correct by hitting the green check by the answer.

Comment: If you use an array formula with entire column references then you're forcing Excel to perform an incredible amount of unnecessary calculation. If, for example, there is only actually data as far as row 1000, then that formula is being forced to calculate more than TWO MILLION cells than are actually necessary, an astonishing number for a single formula.

Comment: @XORLX you are correct, I usually put that note in but was caught up in what it was used for.  I will add it now.

Comment: Also there might be a minor advantage in using  the ADDRESS function, so it would update if columns were inserted:- =ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(IF(A:A="F",B:B)),IF(A:A="F",B:B),0),COLUMN(B:B),4)